# Assigning unique integral identifier for types, compile-time

Tags: c++, compile-time

I wonder whether some template meta-programming facility allows one to assign unique integral identifiers for different types, i.e. something like this:

```
class Type;
enum { id = identifier<Type>() /* or identifier<Type>::id, ... */ };
static_assert(id == identifier<Type>(), "...");
```

The hard part, I think, is that the identifier should remain the same across a single compilation (which is not necessarily the same thing as a compilation unit). But of course, as I don't know the technique or if it's possible at all, I really don't *know* what's the hardest part.

**Edit:** How about within a single compilation unit?

Comment: Sure. Anything goes, as they say.

Comment: Is there a possible solution? To be unique, it should be managed over compile units, which makes it impossible to be done in compile time. I needed a similar facility once before but couldn't find one.

Comment: @user1030861: allthough if you use a common compiler, options and ABI you'd probably get a long way with a strong hash of the `typeid(T).name()`. You'd be _out of the standards_ for sure, but it might work out

Comment: @user1030861 - I was wondering about using `typeid` on a known, fixed type in a `constexpr` function, but it seems that's not legal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alescandrescu. He analyses this problem quite deeply, template meta-programming heavily involved, in one of the chapters about abstract factories. The conclusion is that there is no absolutely portable way how to map a C++ type to integral type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeid` at runtime for classes with virtual functions.

Other types lack the necessary representation and global ordering, the compiler has no way of knowing all compilation units and the linker has no concept of a type. The most common workaround is using **Boost.MPL** to build a vector of all interesting types and use the index in that vector as an identifier.