# A compile time ordering on types

Tags: c++

I've been looking for a way to get an ordering on types at compile time. This would be useful, for example, for implementing (efficient) compile-time type-sets.

One obvious way to do it would be if there were a way to map every type to a unique integer.  An answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111273/626288) on that topic succinctly captures why that's difficult, and it seems like it would apply equally to any other way of trying to get an ordering:

> the compiler has no way of knowing all compilation units and the linker has no concept of a type

Indeed, the challenge to the compiler would be considerable: it has to make sure that, in any invocation, for any source file, it returns the same integer for a given type / it returns the same ordering between any two given types, but at the same time, the universe of types is open and it has no knowledge of any types outside of the current file. A hard problem.

The idea I had is that types have names. And by the laws of C++, as far as I know the fully qualified name of a type must be unique across the entire program, otherwise you will get errors or undefined behaviour of some sort or another.

- If two types have the same name, then they are the same type.
- If two types are the same type, then either they have the same name, or they are typedefs for one another. The compiler has full knowledge of typedefs.

Names are strings, and strings have an ordering. So if I have it right, you could define a globally consistent ordering on types based on their names. More specifically, the ordering between any two types would be the ordering between the names of the types with the typedefs fully resolved. (Having a type behave differently from its typedefs would be problematic.)

Of course, standard C++ doesn't have any facilities for retrieving the names of types.

My questions are:

- Do I have anything wrong? Are there any reasons this wouldn't, in theory, work?
- Are there any compilers which give you access to the names of types (and ideally their typedef-resolved forms) at compile time as a language extension?
- Is there any other way it could be done? Are there any compilers which do?

(I recognize that it's not polite to ask more than one question in the same question, but it seemed strange to post three separate questions with the same basic throat-clearing preceding them.)

Comment: I suspect you're using the wrong programming language.

Comment: (And, FWIW, I think your question grouping is probably fine in this case. They're tightly sequential.)

Comment: "Of course, standard C++ doesn't have any facilities for retrieving the names of types." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid

Comment: I too tried to implement type ordering in C++ and it looks like it's impossible within Standard C++. One could probably write a GCC plugin to do this, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @FailedDev This is a runtime facility, not a compile-time one.

Comment: @n.m. U are right, I misread the q.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, why in particular?

Answer (score 1):

> the fully qualified name of a type must be unique across the entire program

But of course, that's only true if you consider seperate anonymous namespaces in different translation units to have *different names* in some sense, and have some way to figure out what they are.

The only sense in which I'm aware they really do have different names is in mangled linker symbols; you *may* (depending on the compiler) be able to get that from `type_info::name()`, but it isn't guaranteed, is limited to types with RTTI, and anyway doesn't seem to be declared as a `constexpr` so you can't use the value at compile time.

The ordering produced by `type_info::before()` naturally has the same limitations.

Out of interest, what are you trying to achieve with your compile-time type ordering?

Comment: Anonymous namespaces! Very good point. I forgot about them. Note that the function of fully qualified names in my question isn't necessarily to expose them directly, but (hypothetically) as a mechanism for implementing a consistent compile-time ordering on types. To that end (if I'm thinking correctly) it almost doesn't matter where in the ordering we put them, as long as it's consistent. Regarding type_info::name(), the typeid operator itself unfortunately isn't constexpr, so that doesn't get us very far.

Comment: As for my use case: I want to implement a system of record types where the "field labels" can be shared between record types. But the order of fields in a record shouldn't matter. The "names" of field labels are represented by dummy types. In practice you have to write them down in some order or another, but Record<FooField, BarField> should be completely interoperable with Record<BarField, FooField>. So the types should behave more like a set than a list. And for implementing a set you'd rather like to have operator<(). It's possible without, but nicer with.

Comment: (And for the record, another thing I had completely forgotten about is type_info::before(). My jumping off point was more the way GHC/Haskell implements its Typeable class. But if typeid and type_info::before() were constexpr (is there a reason it's possible to implement them at runtime but wouldn't be at compile time?) that would basically solve my wish right there.)

Comment: There's a possibly easier way to get type-indexed field access, using a recursively-defined template. I think it's described in Modern C++ Design, but I'll edit it into my answer tomorrow if you need it (your Record is essentially an elaborated tuple).

Comment: Type-indexed field access isn't a problem, I don't need a type-level type ordering for that. (I'm indeed going to be using a recursively defined template, and yes indeed it's an elaborated tuple -- in fact a "plain" tuple is probably what the implementation will forward to.) What's not so trivial is things like the copy constructor, assignment operator, etc., which should be indifferent to the order of the type template parameters. (And if I have an ordering on types I can always put them in some canonical order and go with that, instead of some double-loop with equality tests.)